# Delete blank space before and after axis column and complete the color in last area

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have the chart in my report that I have create with ReportingServices.
The report works but I want to change two properties, so I don't know how can I find its.

The chart is this:

[image]

If you see, there is a blank space before "Mon" and after "Sun", I don't want that blank space before and after the Day.

For second I want to extend the Red Area to end of the chart.
It's possibile this???

Regards

I try to change this properties:

ChartArea properties, then I have selected Custom Position, then I have set Left properties = 0 but the result is the same

Comment: You should split your question into multiple ones to keep Stackoverflow clean and readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You right click on the axis-> Horizontal Axis Properties->

when the property screen appears you set Side Margins to Disabled.